# Determining the old MX record

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, email-server, mx-record

Our sysadmin created our mailserver years ago before he left. We recently decided to use gmail as our mail app and they required us to change the MX record to point to them on amazon route 53 app. I need to determine the old MX record we had. It's got to be somewhere on the server. I'm pretty sure it's mail.server.con. How do I retrieve this?

Comment: I'm not understanding why you need to know what it used to be. Can you clarify?

Comment: Find the person who changed the MX record?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you should have a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Answer (score -4):

Erm..... First hit from google (search string mx record lookup) was:

http://mxtoolbox.com/

For those who have never used it, it has a history button to show previous mx records for a given domain.

Comment: The history feature only shows what lookups mxtoolbox.com has done previously for the record. If it has never done any, then you will find nothing.

Comment: @Colyn1337 true, but that only works if someone had done a lookup on that site previously for that server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton again, it was a google search, there's tons of tools available if that specific one wasn't querying at that time.

Comment: When _I_ did a Google search, I got completely different results.. :)